# tshark 1.8.2: invalid option -- 'Y'

Tags: filter, wireshark, tshark

I am running following command with tshark 1.8.2

**tshark -nr 2calls.pcap  -Y "ip.src eq 207.239.33.54 || ip.dst eq 207.239.33.54 " -w final.cap**

But always encounter this type of error.
**tshark: invalid option -- 'Y'**

Running **tshark -h** does not show display filter option. 
I tried installing tshark 1.12 on my debian (Linux debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux) but no luck, a lot of dependencies are involved there.

How can i run the above command or install tshark 1.12 on my debian server?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If I recall correctly, the flag was -R back on 1.8?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Perfectly works